# render the clicked tab R dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I am working on `shinydashboard` app with multiple tabs & I would like to render the tab content only when it is clicked on. I'm using shinydashboard library to create my dashboard, the application takes around 30 sec to work and I would like to optimize it so it will render the selected tab only.

UI code sample

```
    dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Enrollment Dashboard",titleWidth = 300),
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 300,

    sidebarMenu( 
    menuItem("Descriptive Analysis", icon = icon("right",lib='glyphicon'), tabName = "desc",  
    menuSubItem("Statistics",icon = icon("right",lib='glyphicon'),tabName = "kpi" ),
    menuSubItem("Marketing" ,icon = icon("right",lib='glyphicon'), tabName = "markd")),
    menuItem("Predictive Analysis", icon = icon("right",lib='glyphicon'), tabName = "predictive",
    menuItem("Enrollment Number", icon = icon("right",lib='glyphicon'), tabName = "predictive",
    menuSubItem("Enrollment prediction - overall" ,icon = icon("right",lib='glyphicon'), tabName = "predictivesummary"),
    menuItem("Enrollment prediction per program" , icon = icon("right",lib='glyphicon'),tabName = "predictiveprograms"))


dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet" , type = "text/css" , href = "reload.CSS")),
  renderText("test"),
  tabItems(tabItem(tabName  = "kpi",
                   frow1<-fluidRow(

                     infoBoxOutput("value1",width = 3),tags$style("#value1 { padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;color: blue; font-size: 13px;background:#F4F4F4;}"),
                     infoBoxOutput("value2",width = 3),tags$style("#value2 { padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;color: blue; font-size: 13px;background:#F4F4F4;}"),
                     box
                     (uiOutput("value3"),
                       width = 1,
                       height = 130


                     ),
                     box
                     (uiOutput("value5"),
                       width = 1,
                       height = 130


                     ),
                     box
                     (uiOutput("value6"),
                       width = 1,
                       height = 130


                     ),
                     infoBoxOutput("value4",width = 3),tags$style("#value4 {padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;color: blue; font-size: 13px;background:#F4F4F4;}")
                   ),



                   frow2<-fluidRow(

                     box(
                       title = "Inquiry (Actuals- Green/Target- Light Grey)"
                       ,width = 3
                       ,height = 330
                       ,status = "warning"
                       ,solidHeader = FALSE
                       ,collapsible = TRUE

                       ,dataTableOutput("plot")

                     ),

                     box(

                       title = "Applied (Actuals- Green/Target- Light Grey)"
                       ,width = 3
                       ,status = "warning"
                       ,solidHeader = FALSE
                       ,collapsible = TRUE
                       ,plotlyOutput("applyplot", height = 270)
                     ),

                     box(
                       title = "Processed (Actuals- Green/Target- Light Grey)"
                       ,width = 3
                       ,status = "warning"
                       ,solidHeader = FALSE
                       ,collapsible = TRUE
                       ,plotlyOutput("processedplot", height = 270)
                     ),

                     box(
                       title = "Enrolled (Actuals- Green/Target- Light Grey)"
                       ,width = 3
                       ,status = "warning"
                       ,solidHeader = FALSE
                       ,collapsible = TRUE
                       ,plotlyOutput("enrolledplot", height = 270)
                     )),


                   frow3<-fluidRow(

                     box(
                       title = "Enrollment Yearly Progress Growth / Programs "
                       ,width = 12
                       ,solidHeader = FALSE
                       ,collapsible = TRUE
                       ,status = "warning",

                       tabsetPanel( type = 'pills',
                         tabPanel('Admissions',
                                  plotlyOutput("threerow", height = 350)

                                  ),
                         tabPanel('Financial',plotlyOutput("frow", height = 350)),
                         tabPanel('Enrollment',plotlyOutput("erow", height = 350)) 
                       )


                     ))
  ),

  tabItem(tabName = "predictivesummary" , 

          frow5<- fluidRow(
            box("Yearly Predictive Analysis"
                ,width = 12
                ,solidHeader = FALSE
                ,collapsible = TRUE
                ,status = "warning"
                ,plotlyOutput("plot_forecast" , height = 350) )),

          frow501<- fluidRow(
            box("Overall Prediction Yearly - Tabular"
                ,width = 12
                ,solidHeader = FALSE
                ,collapsible = TRUE
                ,status = "warning"
                ,dataTableOutput("year_table" , height = 350) ))

          )
```

Server

```
  shinyServer(function(input, output ,session ) {

    output$value1 <- renderInfoBox({

    infoBox(
  h2(total.TotalInquiry()),
  h4(percentage.TotalInquiry())
  ,tags$h5('Inquries - Target : ' , total.TargetInquiry())
  ,
  icon = icon("question-sign",lib='glyphicon')
)})


             output$value2 <- renderInfoBox({
          infoBox(
          h2(total.Applied()),
            h4(percentage.Applied())
       ,h5('Applied-Target:',target.Applied())
      ,
     icon = icon("thumbs-up",lib='glyphicon'))
    })


       output$value3 <- renderText({
           paste0(h3(ProcessedA.Accepted()) ,
          paste0(percentagepA.Accepted(),'%'),
          paste0(),
         h5('Processed:' , ProcessedT.Accepted()))
})

             output$value5 <- renderText({enter code here
paste0(h3(Processed.Rejected()),h6('Rejected:' ))
})

            output$value6 <- renderText({
paste0(h3(Processed.Dropped()),h6('Withdrawan:' ))

})

          output$value4 <- renderInfoBox({
infoBox(
  #tags$h2(total.enrolled() ,'~' , percentage.enrolled())
  tags$h2(total.enrolled()), 
  h4(percentage.enrolled())
  ,tags$h5('Enrolled-Target:',target.enrolled())
  ,
  #color = "olive" , fill = TRUE
  icon = icon("check",lib='glyphicon') )
})


        output$plot <- DT::renderDataTable(expr ={
g <- IA.Applied()
      } , options = list(dom = 't',scrollX = TRUE,autowidth = TRUE,columnDefs = list(list(width = '10px', targets = c(1,3))))) 



output$applyplot <-  renderPlotly(expr ={ 

g <- IAA.Applied() %>%
  mutate(group = 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Program, Applied_Act)) +
  ylim(0,150)+
  geom_col(fill = "#b0e0e6") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Applied), position = position_dodge(0.3),family = "Times New Roman",size = 3)+
  geom_col(aes(y = applied_Tar, group = group), color = "#e7e7e7" ,fill = "#A3A9D1", alpha=0.3) +

  theme_classic()+
  labs(x = "", y = "")
ggplotly(g, tooltip = "Applied")


})


           output$processedplot <- renderPlotly(expr ={  
g <- IA.processed() %>%
  mutate(group = 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Program, Act_Processed)) +
  ylim(0,150)+
  geom_col(fill = "#b0e0e6") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Processed), position = position_dodge(0.3),family = "Times New Roman",size = 3)+
  geom_col(aes(y = Tar_processed, group = group), color = "#e7e7e7" ,fill = "#A3A9D1", alpha=0.3) +
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x = "", y = "")
ggplotly(g, tooltip = "Processed")
})
```

Comment: I don't think Shiny should be rendering any of your server side outputs before they're visible.

Answer (score 1):

@SmokeyShakers is right, Shiny is built so that the server side only renders when visible (i.e. you click on a tab or unhide a table).

I would look at the data you are pulling in and any data manipulation you are doing and seeing if that is the cause of the 30 seconds.

I would use the package `profvis` to do an analysis on your app.

If the data manipulation/reading is the cause there are multiple options such as running a separate process to do the data manipulation and putting the data into a global variable.